# How can I use asp.net mvc routing to call a different ActionResult method and display a different URL than what is actually there?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, controller, asp.net-mvc-routing

Lets say I have a Controller class called ProductController.

I'll use Samsung as a hypothetical product category.

I have an Html.ActionLink on a page that looks like this

```
~/Product/Samsung?t=Sony
```

Now lets say I don't have an ActionResult method named Samsung.

But lets say I have more links like the one above like

```
~/Product/Toshiba?t=LG

~/Product/Sony?t=Dynex
```

Never mind the t=? part.

Is there a way that I can make all of these ActionLinks hit the same ActionResult method in my Product Controller?

```
public ActionResult TelevisionCategory()
{
}
```

Like some sort of URL routing so that any URL in a specific format will hit the TelevisionCategory method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you just need a custom route that takes an identifier as a second URL segment instead of an action name.

Something like the following should suffice (you'll need to add this above the default route in your route config):

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Products",                                           
    "Product/{category}",                            
    new { controller = "Product", action = "TelevisionCategory" }  
);
```

Then, your action method should look like this:

```
public ActionResult TelevisionCategory(string category)
```

See [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/creating-custom-routes-cs) for more on creating custom routes.

If using MVC5 is an option, you can also use [attribute routing](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5.aspx), which is a little more intuitive and succinct.

Comment: Will the mapping above still allow for the URL to display as Product/Samsung?

Comment: @user1977591 Yup, that's the whole reason I wrote it!

Comment: Thank you sir let me give it a shot and see if I can get it working.